# R - parLapply - spit tasks into own portions

Tags: r, lapply, workload

I have a function like this:

`parLapply(cl, 1:400, function(exponent) 2^exponent)`

R would now split the tasks into even portions for each core.

How can i change that to, lets say:

100 - Core_0
50 - Core_1
...

?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your vector from 1 to 400 into a list, something like shown below:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  even = {
    res1 <- unlist(parLapply(cl, 1:4000, function(x) {
      2^x
    }))
  },
  odd = {
    res2 <- unlist(parLapply(cl, list(1:3000, 3001:4000), function(x) {
      2^x
    }))
  },
  times = 5
)
```

Comment: For some reason "list(1:3000, 3001:4000)" works fine with simple functions, like x^2 and so on. It does not work with my fancy magic stuff. It only calculates the first number, e.g. 1 and 3001. I am using clusterArrayLB now.